# Jest does not recognize my custom typings

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs

I have a typescript project which is requiring a personal library that is added to my `package.json` from its git repo built as a commonjs lib. When I run my build script `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d --config webpack/webpack.dev.js`, everything compiles correctly. However, when I run jest `jest --config front/jest.config.js`, it throws the following error:

```
● Test suite failed to run
TypeError: dumblib_1.default is not a constructor

12 | const dumblib = new DumbLib(vars)
```

When go into the entrypoint of the lib which is just a node project compiled from es6 to commonjs, the bundle shows this at the end of the file:

```
module.exports = DumbLib;
```

The lib isn't typescript so I have a typings file in my main project for the dumblib import.

```
declare module 'dumblib' {
  .
  .
  .

  export default class DumbLib {
    constructor(vars: Vars)
    .
    .
    .
  }

}
```

Like I said, it seems that the typescript compiler sees it as everything compiles correctly. However, jest keeps throwing that error. Is there something special that I have to do for jest to recognize my typings? Or is there maybe some other inconsistency that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that actual export of your module does not match with typings. TypeScript expect a "default" exports from a module because of the typings (you say `export default`), but then inside the module class is the whole export.

Doing these 2 things should help:

1. When you import the module make sure it is like this:

```ts
import * as dumblib from "dumblib";
```

2. in your type definition it should be:

```ts
declare module 'dumblib' {

  class DumbLib {
    // ...
  }

  namespace DumbLib {
    interface Foo {
      bar: string
    }
  }

  export = DumbLib
}
```

Comment: Hrm... I also have another interface exported from that module, when I make your changes I see this in my linter: ` An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.`

Comment: @unflores I've updated an example to include namespace which is how you can export more things from the module.